# How to setup S2S Postback call in Flutter?

Tags: php, flutter, dart, callback, postback

I am trying to setup S2S Callbacks to check for a survey completion for Pollfish (https://www.pollfish.com/docs/s2s). 
1. My question is that how do these callbacks work? 
2. Do I have to have my own server to verify these callbacks, if so how do I set one up using Firebase if in any way possible?
3. Do I get to see the url callback in my debug console after a survey completion?

I have never used PHP before, so I don't have any knowledge about this or how to go about it using my Flutter app.

Comment: hello have you gotten any solution

Comment: Not yet, it has something to do with PHP apparently  @JesusLovesYou

Comment: ohh thats bad so what are you doing now.. any other survey company?

Comment: hello have you gotten any solution